# How to display data in multiple lines in one cell using excel export in laravel

Tags: html, laravel, laravel-excel

I have a nayjest table, and I want to export the data in this table into an excel file.

But I am having trouble formatting the data in their cells.

For example, I want to export this data in laravel nayjest table as-is in the excel file,

[image: Imgur]

But after exporting, this is what is being displayed in the excel file,

[image: Imgur]

As you can see, the data that was supposed to be in multiple lines are now in a single line.

This is the code that I currently have. I am using ExcelExport to export the data into the file,

```
$cfg = (new GridConfig())
...
(new FieldConfig)
    ->setName('S_CODE')
    ->setLabel('Course Code')
    ->setCallback(function ($val, $row) {
        $stud_results = StudResult::where('SESSI', $sessi)
          ->where('SEMESTER', $semester)
          ->where('MATRIC_NO', $data->MATRIC_NO)
          ->get();
        global $currentStudResults;
                        $currentStudResults = $stud_results;
        $table = '<table>';
        foreach ($currentStudResults as $stud_result) {
          $table .= '<tr><td>'
          $table .= $stud_result->S_CODE;
          $table .= '</td></tr>';
          }

        $table = '</table>'
        return $table;
        })
,
...
->setComponents([
     (new THead)
         ->setComponents([
            (new OneCellRow)
                ->setRenderSection(RenderableRegistry::SECTION_END)
                ->setComponents([
                    new RecordsPerPage,
                    new ColumnsHider,
                    (new ExcelExport)
                        ->setFileName(strtoupper('Student Course History') . ' - ' . date('Y-m-d')),
                    (new HtmlTag)
                        ->setContent('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span> Filter')
                        ->setTagName('button')
                        ->setRenderSection(RenderableRegistry::SECTION_END)
                        ->setAttributes([
                            'class' => 'btn btn-success btn-sm',
                         ]),
                  ]),
            (new ColumnHeadersRow),
            (new FiltersRow),
          ]),
       (new TFoot),
]);
```

This is the expected result to be in the excel file,

[image: Imgur]

Is there any way to reformat the excel file to follow my output?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve that by adding some line brakes here:

```
 foreach ($currentStudResults as $stud_result) {
          $table .= '<tr><td>'
          $table .= $stud_result->S_CODE.'</br>';
          $table .= '</td></tr>';
          }
```

Comment: I have tried the line break also tried using <p>. But it does not affect the excel file. It's still in a single line cell...

Comment: Try using '\n' instead.

Comment: unfortunately, html does not support \n... it turns into normal string